# what is the cleanest way to get rounded corners on images using html/css? (crossbrowser)

Tags: html, rounded-corners

I've fixed image size. And I want to achieve rounded corners through html/css.

Options I'm thinking about is to overlay image with four corner png. Using img:after and content. But unfortunately img:after is purely supported across browsers, let alone compatibility with IE 6.7.

Is there any simple clean way to achieve this?

In theory I could also create div with corner background and make it go absolute over the image... but that would break save as functionality.......

any ideas?

Comment: Do you HAVE to have IE6/7 compatibility? Because otherwise using css would be just fine.

Comment: It usually isn't worth the effort in getting trivial cosmetic effects to work in IE version ancient.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support border-radius either... ignoring 6.7 might be an option, but IE8 has bigger share...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always [CSS3 <strike>rounded corners</strike> border radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) which has very good support in every modern browser, then the [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) polyfill for older versions of IE.

Comment: +1 CSS3Pie is the best option. Use standard CSS for all browsers except IE, and add CSS3Pie to make IE also understand the same CSS. Beats every other solution hands down.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about css3pie, but it's kind of slow with rendering... but oh well, that or just leave out all IE users... they have to ditch that crap someday!

Comment: That's the way I look at it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with the fact that browsers that don't support border-radius will show plain old square images, you could use this jQuery script to automatically wrap your images in div's and give them corners:

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/roundedimagecorners/
(View the source to get the js and see how it's used)

Here's an article that I've written that explains the background to this script:
http://www.swedishfika.com/2010/03/19/rounded-corners-on-images-with-css3-2/

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

To make border round in IE there is little work around for that. Please have a look at this [link](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)